# Q_ENUMS in PyQt4

Tags: python, enums, pyqt, signals-slots, qtcpsocket

I would like to use facilities of enumeration of Qt. I saw in documentation of the module of QtCore there is a macros of Q_ENUMS, but I do not know and information how to use him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python (and PyQt), the way to create an enum is like this:

```
class MyEnum(object):
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
```

If you need more functionality than that, please give more details of what you are trying to do.

**EDIT**

Looking at the documentation for [QAbstractSocket.stateChanged](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#stateChanged) I can see it refers to "Creating Custom Qt Types". I am not aware of any need for registering metatypes in PyQt4, so all you need to do to use this signal is connect it to an appropriate handler:

```
class Socket(QTcpSocket):
    def __init__(self):
        QTcpSocket.__init__(self)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)

    def handleStateChanged(self, state):
        print state
```

Comment: I must pass a signal the change of some state into an object, and also to check data in a slot. It is so done in the class of QTcpSocket - signal changeState

Comment: Thank you, it opened my eyes. Really, registration of metatypes there be no need. I will avail grant enum(...)